# How can I keep my previous recipients list in Mail.app from containing addresses I have not sent emails to?

Tags: macos, mail.app

From Mail's help documentation:

> Mail keeps a list of **the email addresses you send messages to**, and uses the list to suggest or complete addresses for you when you send email. You can delete obsolete or incorrect addresses from the list so Mail stops suggesting them, and use the list to quickly see or add people in the Contacts app.

(emphasis added)

Spam addresses are appearing in my previous recipients list. About once a month I go in and find hundreds of new addresses that I have never sent an email to and are clearly spam email addresses.

I know how to delete these addresses by hand in Mail > Window > Previous Recipients, but it is a pretty annoying process. I really want to know why they are appearing and (or) how to keep that from happening.

Comment: Do you want to retain the ability to use the autosuggest/complete feature and only want to stop the other addresses from adding on, or would it be a viable solution to just disable the autosuggest feature completely?

Comment: @smoooosher I want to be able to use the autosuggest feature.

Comment: That's a mightily tempting bounty... yet I can't even find a way to make it add to that list from incoming emails. It will only add ones I do reply to. I'd be tempted to say, as it's obviously been happening for quite some time you're unlikely to be mistaken... how about testing on a fresh user account on the Mac, set up mail again & see if it still happens [I know, total pita to do, but might be the first step in elimination]

Comment: Yeah, the hard thing is that it happens like once a month (or three I haven't noticed a pattern yet) so it would take a while to figure out. I have four different accounts and I don't even know which account is adding the addresses. The only info I have is the address, the name connected with it, and the date last "used" that is in that window.

Comment: maybe I'll just get a genius bar appointment next time I notice the addresses appearing. Thinking back, I've probably deleted the addresses three times since I've posted this, so it is closer to three months than every month.

Comment: You don't have any kind of "out of office reply" that could be running, do you? Something generating actual replies, rather than finding the ghost in the machine. [Pure guess, worth a shot]

Comment: Another possibility:  Can you have been hacked?  Is your mac being used by a spammer to send out messages

Comment: You've checked the sentmail folder for actual outdoing messages matching the spurious addresses?

Comment: No out of office reply set. I have been wondering if my computer was sending spam, but there is nothing in my sent mailbox, and I'd imagine the addresses would look more genuine if it was sending spam. These look like the addresses you get spam from. But I can't rule that possibility out. It could be that whatever is sending the messages is deleting the sent messages but not the addresses from this list.

Comment: Last ditch attempt... anything in `/var/mail/` ?

Comment: It might be possible to write a script that compares messages that you've sent to the previous recipients list, and eliminate the ones that don't match. But I don't know where that's stored, so I can't give you an answer in the next 23 minutes :P

Comment: there is a zero K text edit document in /var/mail with my username

Comment: There are still 23 hours until the bounty points disappear.

Comment: & I don't ***need*** them, but I'd ***like*** them... I'm still thinking... :)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry I can't give any more info. I am kicking myself because I deleted a big chunk of addresses right before coming over and posting the bounty. I should have kept them around, but it is so irritating to see 42 spammy addresses pop up when I'm typing out an email address.

Comment: I haven't seen any new spammy addresses added since March 2016, so perhaps Apple finally fixed this issue.